# How to add Firebase Admin SDK to a Google Cloud Platform and communicate with an app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've been making an Android application which requires some users to have administrative controls when logged in. I have researched into how this is possible and can see that it requires the use of Firebase Admin SDK running on a server. Now the problem i am having is how can i actually set this up to communicate with my application?

This is the first time i have tried making an android application and used servers. I  have read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#windows) but this still hasn't made it clear to me of the components i need and how to piece them together. So far i have prepared...

- Android Application (Developed in Java using Android Studio)
- Google Cloud Platform (Server App to run admin SDK)

... but now i need to understand how i can run the admin SDK on my Google Cloud Function and use this for authorisation in my android app. Any advice or direction to helpful documentation would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've never done something like this before, I'd recommend starting with [**callable** Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). The documentation has a nice example of how to implement these and call them from your Android code.

Inside the Cloud Function you can then use the Admin SDK to access for example Firebase Authentication. See the documentation [importing the required modules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app) for an example of how to set up the Admin SDK, and then the documentation of the Admin SDK for an example of how to [get a list of users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).

Comment: I'll give these documentation a look cheers. Also i can see the HTTP callable documentation writes some code in a `index.js` file. Does this mean i should be developing this code in Node.js?

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase are written in Node.js indeed.

Comment: i have been able to deploy test callable functions to my Google Cloud Platform, however it only works when i am using typescript but the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) only gives examples in javascript. Do you know any resources that provides detals in typescript?

Comment: All JavaScript is also valid TypeScript, so the examples from the documentation should run without modifications. In addition, there are a lot of examples in this repo: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples